# HTML5 History API Back Button

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I'm using an ajax call to update a part of my page, it's for a search function. When I do the search, I update the url. Example: mysite.com/products becomes mysite.com/products?search=blabla

But when I press the back button, only the url changes and not the content of the page.

This is the function I use to set the history:

```
function setHistory(data, url) {
    var search = $("#Search").val();
    url = url.replace('search_input', search);
    history.pushState(data, "", url);
}
```

The `data` is what is changed on the page and the `url` is the new url to push to the history. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Shouldn't the page update itself if I use the back button? It won't work in chrome nor in IE 10.

Comment: see https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Comment: @jalynn2 — That just fakes support for the history API in older browsers, as far as I know it won't automatically save and restore the state when the user goes back.

Comment: @Quentin -- Yes, you are correct. I keep forgetting that some people have the luxury of supporting only modern browsers

Comment: My support for older browsers with the history API tends to be "Here, have a regular link and I'll build the page on the server".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen for a `popstate` event and change the page back.

```
addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
    event.state; // this contains the state data from `pustState`. Use it to decide what to change the page back to.
}
```

See also, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Comment: This works. Thanks! I also found out
    window.onpopstate = function (event) { ... };
also works.